# Python selenium, scraper da amazon, não consigo encontrar o nome do produtos

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Código

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

objeto = ('teclado')
os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/SeleniumDrivers"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.amazon.es/-/pt')
driver.maximize_window()
cookies = driver.find_element_by_id('sp-cc-accept')
cookies.click()
pesquisa = driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox')
pesquisa.click()
pesquisa.send_keys(objeto)
lupa = driver.find_element_by_id('nav-search-submit-button')
lupa.click()
```

Depois disto já tentei imensas formas de encontrar o titulo, usando o `.find_element` e as suas variações mas nunca consigo, é para um trabalho de Aplicações Informáticas do 12º ano, para além do titulo estava também à procura do preço, muito obrigado

++

O códgio html com o titulo que quero copiar está assim

```
<span class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal'> == 0$
 "Kensington ValuKeyboard Teclado com fios para PC, portátil, PC de secretária, computador e notebook, o teclado é compatível com Dell, Hacer, HP, Samsung e muito mais, com design de UK, preto (1500109ES)" == 0$
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão, trabalhar com XPATH quando utilizar no selenium, ele costuma responder melhor.

Fiz a adição das linhas abaixo no seu código e trouxe o print do nome, imagino que é isso que você queira. O print é apenas a demonstração visual, você pode trabalhar como quiser o texto e também utilizar o mesmo critério para trazer outras informações que você deseja da página.

```
nome = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/a/span').text

print(nome)
```